# How to change the date format in my data frame using R

Tags: r, date, graph, ggplot2, format

I wanted to plot a graph of n(y-axis) versus date(x-axis) in R, but due to the format of the date displayed in my data, the order of the date wasn't in the correct ascending order. How can I solve this? Appreciate for the help.

```
hybrid <- readWorksheetFromFile(excel.file, sheet="ResultSet", header=TRUE)
wb <- loadWorkbook(excel.file)
setMissingValue(wb,value=c("NA"))
hybrid1 <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="ResultSet", header=TRUE)
```

I used the dplyr function. Suppose each Pub.Number have a unique code & I replaced it with one. Then, I count the number of it for a certain date.

```
hybrid <- mutate(hybrid1, n=sum(Publication.Number=1))
p1 <- select(hybrid1, Publication.Date, n)
pt <- count(p1, Publication.Date, wt=n)
```

The output look like this:

```
pt
Source: local data frame [627 x 2]

   Publication.Date     n
              (chr) (dbl)
1        01.01.2013     1
2        01.01.2014     8
3        01.01.2015    10
4        01.02.2012     3
5        01.03.2012    16
6        01.04.2015     2
7        01.05.2012     1
8        01.05.2013     7
9        01.05.2014    23
10       01.06.2011     1
..              ...   ...
```

Then, I plotted it but R recognized Pub.Date as character

```
qplot(x=Publication.Date, y=n, data=pt, geom="point")

x <- hybrid1[,2]
class(x)
[1] "character"
```

[The graph I've plotted is a mess because of the wrong order of the date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzS4s.png)

I tried using the as.Date function but it seems that it's not complete (I'm using R version 3.2.2)

```
> pt[,1] <- as.Date(pt[,1], format='%d.%m.%Y’)
+
```

Comment: You want to check how you create date objects (e.g., as.Date()). Here is a [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) for you. You may want to consider using  `scale_x_date()`. The info is [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the usual course of data input with R, values like " 01.01.2013" will become factor variables. Since they are  not in one of the two "stadard Date formats: YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY-MM-DD, they cannot be input directly as "Date"s with "colClasses" unless you build an "as.DT" method. You will need to make sure they are character vectors either by using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in a read function or by coercing to character with `as.character` after they are input. That header you have displayed makes me think this data has been manipualtes dsomehow, perhaps with functions in the dplyr package?

```
res <- structure(list(Publication.Date = structure(1:10, .Label = c("01.01.2013", 
 "01.01.2014", "01.01.2015", "01.02.2012", "01.03.2012", "01.04.2015", 
 "01.05.2012", "01.05.2013", "01.05.2014", "01.06.2011"), class = "factor"), 
     n = c(1L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 23L, 1L)), .Names = c("Publication.Date", 
 "n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
 "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

> res
   Publication.Date  n
1        01.01.2013  1
2        01.01.2014  8
3        01.01.2015 10
4        01.02.2012  3
5        01.03.2012 16
6        01.04.2015  2
7        01.05.2012  1
8        01.05.2013  7
9        01.05.2014 23
10       01.06.2011  1

> res$Publication.Date <- as.Date( as.character(res$Publication.Date), format="%m.%d.%Y")
```

Then you can plot:

```
png();  qplot(x=Publication.Date, y=n, data=res, geom="point"); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I used dplyr & R recognize the Pub.Date as character. I tried using your way but the whole column of Pub.Date turned to NA. I'm still a beginner in R, appreciate your help ~

Comment: "My way" did not use an object created by dplyr-functions and "your way" is still a complete mystery since you posted no code showing what created the `NA`'s. You should edit you question to include the output from `dput` on your object and the code if you want specific assistance.

Comment: I added the code for the dplyr-functions I used, hope it'll help. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: "not complete" is exactly right. When I saw `format='%d.%m.%Y’`, I noticed  that the closing quote was not a "straight-single-quote" but was rather a "curved -closing-quote". I think you should stop using MS-Word as your editor.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is already. Thank you for all the help so far, your answer is very helpful ~ Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

First convert 'Publication.Date’ to Date format, then order:

using your data:

```
data <- read.table(pipe('pbpaste'),sep='',header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
  data <- data[,-1]
  names(data) <- c('Pub.Date', 'n’)

    Pub.Date  n
1 01.01.2014  8
2 01.01.2015 10
3 01.02.2012  3
4 01.03.2012 16
5 01.04.2015  2
6 01.05.2012  1
7 01.05.2013  7
8 01.05.2014 23
9 01.06.2011  1
```

convert ‘Pub.Date’ to date format:

```
data[,1] <- as.Date(data[,1],format='%d.%m.%Y’)
```

and order:

```
data[order(data$"Pub.Date",data$n), ]

    Pub.Date  n
9 2011-06-01  1
3 2012-02-01  3
4 2012-03-01 16
6 2012-05-01  1
7 2013-05-01  7
1 2014-01-01  8
8 2014-05-01 23
2 2015-01-01 10
5 2015-04-01  2
```

Comment: I tried using the as.Date function but it seems that it's not complete. I added my outcome to the question, please have a look. Really appreciate for your help so far.

Comment: @Juliet.Y, what is the exact error message ? What are your locale settings?  Check your Data Frame with "str" and make sure that "Pub.Date" is not a factor variable before you use the "as.Date" function.